# sass code style with media queries

Tags: sass

I'm doing a code review for sass code and came across using media queries inside the code. Is it a good practice? Are there better alternatives to writing this code?

```
.col-md-push-8 {
    padding-top: 1.5em;
    .btn {
        &.btn-block {
            border: none;
            background-color: $footer-button;
            margin: 1em 0 .5em;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 7px 10px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            &:hover {
                background-color: $footer-button-hover;
            }
            @media (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
                color: #025191;
                &:hover .media span p.media-heading {
                    color: #0070ca;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The code is for illustration purpose only and is not completely shown here.

Comment: That's how I do it. Have a look at the compiled code to see what it is actually doing.

Comment: Glad that helped you, I just upvoted you, don't know why you were downvoted in the first place, I think your question is interesting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what your way to do it is perfectly fine if you're using SASS >= 3.2 (was buggy before).

Just one thing that you could do to define your media queries breakpoints more globally is to create a `mixin` for that purpose that you will re-use on each element you need responsive.

This way when you have to change let's say your min breakpoint, add another or change your media `min-width` to `max-width`, you don't have to do it everywhere.

Some little example assuming you have already defined `$screen-md-min` and `$screen-md-mid` :

```
@mixin custom-media($size) {

    @if ($size == $small) {
         @media (min-width: $screen-md-min) { @content; }
    }
    @else if ($size == $middle) {
         @media (min-width: $screen-md-mid) { @content; }
    }
}
```

And call it like so :

```
.btn {
    &.btn-block {
        ...
        @include custom-media($small) {
            color: #025191;
            &:hover .media span p.media-heading {
                color: #0070ca;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly. you can also use variables as an alternative: `@media #{$bp-until-sm}` where $bp-until-sm is defined as `$bp-until-sm: "only screen and (max-width: 30em)";`

Comment: Yes you're right, but it's now just in the media query mixin, and you don't have to concatenate your strings, seems a little much cleaner I think

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference if you put Media Query inside or outside. It just depends on your preffered style.

**Style 1**

```
.some-class {
  @media (min-width: 700px) {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

**Style 2**

```
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .some-class {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

*Both will compile as:*

```
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .some-class {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sass handles this fine, but that code is going to produce overly qualified selectors and is hardly concise.

There are a number of patterns for writing “better” CSS and Sass, such as [BEM](http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/), [OOCSS](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/), [OOCSS + Sass](http://ianstormtaylor.com/oocss-plus-sass-is-the-best-way-to-css/), and [SMACSS](http://smacss.com/).

There's also a bunch of great information on [Media Queries in Sass](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/responsive-web-design-part-2) that is probably worth a read.